# Import table without clean function from word to excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The code below copies only the values in the table from Word to Excel. Is there any other ways to copy the entire table (including the formats like borders) to excel?

```
Public Sub ImportTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Word
Dim jRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Word Documents (*.doc?),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")
If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file
With wdDoc
    If wdDoc.tables.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    Else
        jRow = 0
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        For TableNo = 1 To wdDoc.tables.Count
            With .tables(TableNo)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                    jRow = jRow + 1
                    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(jRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    Next iCol
                Next iRow
            End With
            jRow = 0
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Next TableNo
    End If
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

*This code was taken from the internet.

Comment: A link to the source of the code would be appropriate. --- Formatting in Word is different from that in Excel. At a minimum, you will need to capture the formatting attributes in the Word table and translate them to similar formats in Excel. It may be possible to paste the entire table as a Word object. However, it would be less available to Excel in those circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply copy/paste...

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
For TableNo = 1 To wdDoc.tables.Count
    .tables(TableNo).Range.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.Range("a1")
        .PasteSpecial
        .Select
    End With
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
Next TableNo
```

However, if you want to avoid the extra sheet that will get created, try the following instead...

```
For TableNo = 1 To wdDoc.tables.Count
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    .tables(TableNo).Range.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.Range("a1")
        .PasteSpecial
        .Select
    End With
Next TableNo
```